# Converting input String to int array with Variable length in java

Tags: java

Here is a snippet of my code. I want to get of user a number with variable length and convert it to int array.
example: input: 352040 , output:{3,5,2,0,4,0}

```
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); 
    System.out.println(" Enter your size number: ");
         int length = in.nextInt();

    System.out.println(" Enter a number: ");
         int number = in.nextInt();

         int[] intArray = null;
         String str = Integer.toString(number);

         for ( int i =0; i < length ;i++)
           intArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(str.charAt(i)));


           System.out.println(Arrays.toString(intArray));
```

This comes up with an error(Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException)
 and I cant understand why.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: you did not creat array at all. you just declare a array reference which point to a null. you need to have new int[length];

Comment: instead of coping and pasting code, try to understand  your issue.

Comment: ok, sure. i have a question: i want to sort a number - i wrote in the example - isn't there a better way to get of user and sort it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to create the array first.

```
     int[] intArray = new int[length];  // Create array
     String str = Integer.toString(number);

     for ( int i =0; i < length -1;i++) 
       intArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(str.charAt(i)));
```

Comment: If you find that this answer is the correct answer to you question you can flag it and up vote it.

Comment: this option will fail in the last index...  `for ( int i =0; i < length -1;i++)` is not correct array iteration....

Comment: This is not my code. This is the original code where I added only the creation of the array to solve the NullPointerException

Comment: excuseme,  i have a question:  i want to sort a number- i wrote in the example - there is no better way to get of user and sort it?

Answer (score 1):

Agree with comments, split("") will work only on `javascript` here is a code snippet that does what OP wants...

```
  String s = "352040";
  int[] intArray = new int[s.length()];
  for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
      intArray[i] = Integer.valueOf(s.substring(i, i+1));
  }  
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(intArray));
```

Comment: Split is a string method, and thus the resulting array is a string array not an integer array.

Answer (score 0):

having an object array needs to go through 2 steps.
you failed to cover the second step.

1. Declaring a Variable to Refer to an Array

> The preceding program declares an array (named anArray) with the
>   following line of code:
>
> // declares an array of integers int[] anArray;

**2. Creating, Initializing, and Accessing an Array**

> **One way to create an array is with the new operator**. The next statement in the ArrayDemo program allocates an array with enough
>   memory for 10 integer elements and assigns the array to the anArray
>   variable.
>
> // create an array of integers anArray = new int[10]; If this
>   statement is missing, then the compiler prints an error like the
>   following, and compilation fails:
>
> ArrayDemo.java:4: Variable anArray may not have been initialized.

How to resolve your issue:

instead of your array variable point to null, point to an array object by creating it like:

```
int[] intArray = new int[length];
```